# Why i can't stop the service?

Tags: android, service, android-notifications, android-checkbox, checkboxpreference

I can't stop my service through checkboxpreferences.This is the CheckBoxPreference code

```
CheckBoxPreference checkBoxPref = (CheckBoxPreference) getPreferenceManager().findPreference("firstDependent");
        checkBoxPref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {            
              public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                  if (newValue.toString().equals("true")) {
                      editor.putBoolean("notification_a", true);
                      editor.commit(); 
                      //sendSimpleNotification();
                      startService(new Intent(settings.this,service.class));
                      Log.d("Check", "startService from checkbox");

                  }
                  else if (newValue.toString().equals("false")){
                      editor.putBoolean("notification_a", false);
                      editor.commit(); 
                     //mNotificationManager.cancel(SIMPLE_NOTIFICATION_ID); 
                      stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),service.class)); 
                      Log.d("Check", "stopService from checkbox"); 
                  }
                  return true;
              }
        });
```

So if the checkbox is unchecked the service would stops but nothing happen. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class YOUR_CLASS extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pianostudio);
...CODE...   
    CheckBox checkBoxPref = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.YOUR_CHECKBOX_ID); 
    checkBoxPref.setOnClickListener(this);
...OTHER CODE...
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.YOUR_ID_CHECKBOX:{       //checkbox per de/selezionare l'idoneita' di un esame
            if (checkBoxPref.isChecked()){
                editor.putBoolean("notification_a", true);
                editor.commit(); 
                //sendSimpleNotification();
                startService(new Intent(settings.this,service.class));
                Log.d("Check", "startService from checkbox");;
            }
            else{
                editor.putBoolean("notification_a", false);
                editor.commit(); 
                //mNotificationManager.cancel(SIMPLE_NOTIFICATION_ID); 
                stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),service.class)); 
                Log.d("Check", "stopService from checkbox"); 
            }
            break;
         }
     }
}
}
```

Comment: italiano?Oro..scusa ma `checkBoxPref.setOnClickListener(this);` lo metto nell'onCreate?

Comment: Ma comunque perchè non andrebbe il mio metodo?

Comment: Non capisco perchè usi CheckBoxPreference? Se ti serve solo un ascoltatore alle checkBox il metodo che ti ho detto io è molto più semplice. Guarda il codice aggiornato

Comment: Perchè mi trovo in settings.java che è la mia preference screen..per questo uso i CheckBoxPreference. Ora provo come dici te

Comment: Allora funziona? Non dovresti aver avuto problemi

Comment: Che tipo di problema? Devi implementare l onclick

Comment: Alt invio sopra a setonclicklistener e aggiungi il metodo è implement l onclick all inizio dove hai public class..

Comment: quindi te dici che anche se sono in un preference screen non cambia nulla e posso utilizzare lo stesso il tuo sistema?

Comment: Certamente! Poi fammi sapere se riesci ed in caso accetta la risposta :)

Comment: Hai per caso Google plus?